# create nested json file managing null values

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I'm working with pyspark and I have the following code that creates a nested json file from a dataframe with some fields (product, quantity, from, to) nested in "requirements". Herunder the code that creates the json an one row as example

```
final2 = final.groupby('identifier', 'plant', 'family', 'familyDescription', 'type', 'name', 'description', 'batchSize', 'phantom', 'makeOrBuy', 'safetyStock', 'unit', 'unitPrice', 'version').agg(F.collect_list(F.struct(F.col("product"), F.col("quantity"),  F.col("from"), F.col("to"))).alias('requirements'))


{"identifier":"xxx","plant":"xxxx","family":"xxxx","familyDescription":"xxxx","type":"assembled","name":"xxxx","description":"xxxx","batchSize":20.0,"phantom":"False","makeOrBuy":"make","safetyStock":0.0,"unit":"PZ","unitPrice":xxxx,"version":"0001","requirements":[{"product":"yyyy","quantity":1.0,"from":"2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","to":"9999-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"},{"product":"zzzz","quantity":1.0,"from":"2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","to":"9999-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"},{"product":"kkkk","quantity":1.0,"from":"2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","to":"9999-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"},{"product":"wwww","quantity":1.0,"from":"2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","to":"9999-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"},{"product":"bbbb","quantity":1.0,"from":"2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","to":"9999-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"}]}
```

The schema of the final2 dataframe is the following:

```
 |-- identifier: string (nullable = true)
 |-- plant: string (nullable = true)
 |-- family: string (nullable = true)
 |-- familyDescription: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- batchSize: double (nullable = true)
 |-- phantom: string (nullable = false)
 |-- makeOrBuy: string (nullable = false)
 |-- safetyStock: double (nullable = true)
 |-- unit: string (nullable = true)
 |-- unitPrice: double (nullable = true)
 |-- version: string (nullable = true)
 |-- requirements: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- product: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- quantity: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- from: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- to: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I'm facing a problem because I have to add to my final dataframe some data with product, quantity, from, to = Null: using the code above I get "requirements":[{}] , but the DB where I write the file (MongoDB) get an error with the empty JSON object because it expects "requirements":[] for null values.

I've tried with

```
 import pyspark.sql.functions as F
 df = final_prova2.withColumn("requirements", 
 F.when(final_prova2.requirements.isNull(), 
 F.array()).otherwise(final_prova2.requirements))
```

but it doesn't work.
Any suggestion on how modify the code? I'm struggling to find a solution (I don't even know if a solution is possible considering the structure required).

Thanks

Comment: Hi all,none that can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if all 4 fields of `requirements` are NULL, not the column itself. One way you can fix this is to adjust the *collect_list* aggregate function when creating *final2*:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

final2 = final.groupby('identifier', 'plant', 'family', 'familyDescription', 'type', 'name', 'description', 'batchSize', 'phantom', 'makeOrBuy', 'safetyStock', 'unit', 'unitPrice', 'version') \
    .agg(F.expr("""
      collect_list(
        IF(coalesce(quantity, product, from, to) is NULL
          , NULL
          , struct(product, quantity, from, to)
        )
      )
    """).alias('requirements'))
```

**Where:**

- we use an SQL expression `IF(condition, true_value, false_value)` to set up the argument for collect_list
- the condition: `coalesce(quantity, product, from, to) is NULL` is to test if all listed 4 columns are NULL, if it's true, return *NULL*, otherwise return *struct(product, quantity, from, to)*